# How to add backslash before Double quotes php

Tags: php, backslash

Here is my string

```
$foldername='xyz';
$str="path\path\".$foldername;
```

It's displaying error while trying above.

I want o/p to be like this

```
path\path\xyz
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks all for quick response.

Answer (score 1):

you have to escape the backslashes too:

```
$str="path\\path\\".$foldername;
```

Comment: Not sure the first backslash has to be escaped.

Comment: it has not, but it's no problem if it is done too. I follow the rule: do it always

Answer (score 1):

Use \\ to escape the backslash itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an extra `\` to escape the backslash:

```
$str = "path\path\\" . $foldername;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why backslash?

As you are working with path, use `/` instead. It will work on every platform.

```
$foldername='xyz';
$str="path/path/".$foldername;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use \\ to escape the backslash itself.

$foldername='xyz';
$str='path\\path\\'.$foldername;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another backslash `\` before the main backslash like so.
`some\\where\\to\\go`